# Is a Family a Function, or the Range of a Function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Halmos'book on naive set theory, Halmos introduced the idea of a "family of sets". He explicitly defined a family to be a function from some indexing set to an indexed set. However, whenever he talks about a family, what he seems to always be refering to is actually the *range* of the family. I get so confused whenever he speaks of families in his text, whether he is speaking about the function or the range of the function is very ambiguous. Does "family" then formally mean the indexing function itself, or perhaps the range of the function? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Formally, a family is the precisely the same thing as a function. Halmos says this himself on the first page of section 9. (Note that many people would call what Halmos calls a family an "[indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family)".)

However, when people use the term "family" instead of "function", it's because they want to emphasise the range of the function as being especially important for their purposes; the domain, or index set, becomes an auxiliary object. Accordingly, it is very common to abuse language and use the term family to refer to the range of a function. This abuse of language also reflects the informal way in which people think of a family $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ in $X$, not as a function $x:I\to X$, but as the same thing as a set, except that all of the elements have been "tagged" with a corresponding index (an element may appear multiple times, with different tags).

For example, the index set could convey a notion of "ordering". If $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are sets, then we could consider the family $x:\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\to \{A,B,C,D\}$ given by $x(0)=B,x(1)=C,x(2)=C,x(3)=A,x(4)=C,x(5)=A$. Then, in practice, we think of $x$ as being the set $\{A,B,C\}$ arranged in a "list" $B,C,C,A,C,A$. We can distinguish between elements that appear more than once in the list, since (for example) the first $A$ that appears has the index $3$, whereas the second $A$ that appears has the index $5$.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, there are two related terms. A [family of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets) is just a collection (possibly a set) of sets. An [indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) is a family of sets combined with an indexing function that maps a set of indexes to members of that family. For most purposes, it's not too important to distinguish between the two since the interesting part is the members of the family and the index is just a way to access or reference those members. If Halmos is being loose with the terminology then that's unfortunate but also probably not unusual.

Answer (score 2):

A family is a set. An indexed family is a function. But all the language we use in practice to describe and work with indexed families pretends that they are still sets (and yes, these would be the ranges of the functions in question). This is at least partially because it would be cumbersome both for the writer and for any reader to completely change the linguistic framework the moment we take a family and make it indexed by putting indices on its elements.

Comment: What is the sum of the family of numbers $$2,2,0,\frac12,0,\frac14,0,\frac18,0,\frac1{16},0,\frac1{32},\cdots\quad ?$$ Note, this doesn't need to be a sequence (an $\mathbb N$-indexed family) for the sum to be defined; i.e. the order doesn't matter. But repetition of elements does matter; the two $2$'s don't collapse into a single $2$. I would say a family is a _multiset_, not a set. (However, some definitions of multisets require finite multiplicity; the infinitely many $0$'s wouldn't be allowed.)

Answer (score 2):

This whole indexed familty of sets notion can be confusing. However, the way I think about it, indexed families of sets can be defined in terms of existing definitions (namely functions). An indexed family of sets $ \{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is just a function on a set $I$ defined by $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}:i\mapsto A_i$, where the $A_i$'s are sets. So, $ \{A_i\}_{i\in I}(i)=A_i$. The range of the function is $\{ A_i|i \in I \} $ and so $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}:I\rightarrow \{ A_i|i \in I \} $. And $ \{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is the set $\{<i,\ A_i>|\ i\in I\}$. Every theorem that is expressed in terms of indexed sets can be, without much effort, rephrased in terms of functions (e.g. replace $ \{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ with a suitably defined $f$, $A_i$ with $f(i)$ and keep the set $I$). It's just that some theorems seem to be more naturally expressed in terms of indexed sets.